# Expression Web 3 - Set Thesaurus

Tags: microsoft-expression, thesaurus

I have recently upgraded from Expression 2 to 3.  It's much better, but I cannot get the Thesaurus to work.

It worked fine before the upgrade. Precise error message 'No thesaurus is available for English (United Kingkdom)'

I am indeed, in the UK.  I have set Tools Page Editor Options to first UK and then USA - no joy.  In truth I don't mind the US thesaurus, it would certainly beat 'No thesaurus'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. It will probably be fixed in the upcoming service pack 1. If you need further details I suggest asking a ms mod on the ms forum at state all you have said above, the more confirmations the better.
http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/web/threads

Tina

Comment: Thank you Tina.  Expression 3 seems 90% better than 2, but 10% worse.